# HTTP Authentication with PHP Sessions and Javascript - but have I got it wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, session-variables, http-status-code-401

I have been working on a mini-project for the last day.

It's a **menu interface** with 4 submenu sections.

Each submenu, when clicked, requests a separate HTTP authentication.

If the user submits the correct authentication, the submenu "unlocks". Otherwise the submenu remains locked.

I've got it to work, and I see why it works but - *and **this** is my question* - it looks **a bit hacky** and I suspect there may be **a much more optimal solution**.

---

## TLDR; Go directly to Step Six (below)

---

## Step One

When I first wrote the menu and the HTTP Authentication Menu popped up, there were **three outcomes**:

1. If the user gives an incorrect response, authentication is requested again
2. If the user gives a correct response, the submenu unlocks
3. If the user ***cancels***... the browser displays a `401 Unauthorised Page` (of course it does...)

---

## Step Two

I wanted the menu to remain visible to the user, so I set up a custom `401 Unauthorised Page` by adding:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /my-custom-401/
```

to my `.htaccess` file

And, since it's a PHP file, I added a Location header redirect:

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/my-menu/');
exit();
```

to the top of the file.

Nope. Do you know what that does? It prevents the Authentication Console from ever popping up. Why? Because, at the point where the console does pop up, the server is already visiting the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` (even though it isn't displaying in the browser until you click on cancel). So if the first thing the server sees is a Location header, it leaves before it ever pops up the console.

---

## Step Three

So, I wrote some html (`<head>`, `<body>` etc.), ditched the PHP Location Header and added a javascript redirect to the `<head>`:

```
<script>window.location.href = '/my-menu/';</script>
```

Definitely better, although now, given that I had already unlocked the submenu (this is the default behaviour behind the scenes - for all those users, who have already been through authentication and don't need to go through it again), what now happens is that just pressing cancel on the console, means I am returned to the menu and (of course) the submenu is now unlocked.

---

## Step Four

So, I went back to my custom `401 Unauthorised Page` I **re-locked** the submenu (which I'd unlocked for users who don't need authentication) prior to the redirect. I'm using **PHP Sessions**, so it looks like this:

```
$_SESSION['My_Submenu_Unlocked'] = FALSE;
```

Behaviour is now ***exactly as intended*** for those users who have already authenticated *and* those users who have not yet authenticated and who go to unlock a submenu and who then:

1. enter incorrect details; ***or***
2. press cancel

But for those users who enter correct details, despite the fact that they are now authenticated, they are redirected back to the menu with a `$_SESSION['My_Submenu_Unlocked'] = FALSE;` flag which means that the submenu does not display as unlocked... even though if they click on it a second time (being authenticated), the menu will then unlock.

---

## Step Five

It's not great user experience to click on something, have it do nothing and then react when you click on it a second time. I wanted the submenu to unlock when I clicked it the first time. For that to happen, I figured, the server (or the browser) would need to recognise that the user had just been redirected from the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` and then auto-click itself on the respective submenu to deliver the intended behaviour.

The auto-clicking isn't a problem - I can do that with `.click()` in javascript. But it quickly became apparent, that if the browser fired the javascript after redirecting from the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` *without a further conditional check* then anyone clicking cancel on the authentication console, would find themselves in an infinite loop of authentication requests, always being redirected to the menu, which then redirected to the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` and so on...

---

## Step Six

... it was then that I stumbled upon what may be a hack, or may be an elegant solution which takes advantage of standard server behaviour in which PHP is processed first, then the server waits for positive user authentication *and only then* does it deliver the HTML and CSS and Javascript to the browser.

Here it is. At the top of the head of the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` I have the following PHP, HTML and Javascript:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Custom 401 Unauthorised Page</title>
';

// CONFIRM THAT SERVER HAS VISITED "401 UNAUTHORISED" AUTHENTICATION PAGE
$_SESSION['Authorisation_Check'] = TRUE;

// AUTHORISATION INSTRUCTIONS
$_SESSION['Selected_Submenu_Unlocked'] = FALSE;

// JAVASCRIPT REDIRECT FOR WHEN AUTHENTICATIONS ARE CANCELLED BY THE USER
echo '<script>window.location.href = \'/my-menu/?locked\';</script>';

echo '
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my-styles.css" />
</head>
';
```

The query string `?locked` in the javascript redirect above is all I need to ensure that the auto-click *never happens* on returning to the menu ***if*** the user presses cancel. Why? Because, apparently, that javascript redirect (with the query string) is only ever processed if the user ***does*** click cancel.

If the user fills in the authentication details correctly, the server still parses through the `<head>`, paying attention to:

```
// CONFIRM THAT SERVER HAS VISITED "401 UNAUTHORISED" AUTHENTICATION PAGE
$_SESSION['Authorisation_Check'] = TRUE;

// AUTHORISATION INSTRUCTIONS
$_SESSION['Selected_Submenu_Unlocked'] = FALSE;
```

but then, after the user responds to the console correctly, it returns to the menu URL (without the query string) before the browser ever gets to process:

```
// JAVASCRIPT REDIRECT FOR WHEN AUTHENTICATIONS ARE CANCELLED BY THE USER
echo '<script>window.location.href = \'/my-menu/?locked\';</script>';
```

I can see why this works, but is this really reliable?

Or is this separation of PHP execution and Javascript execution (with HTTP Authentication in the middle) a robust enough approach to be used and reused in future?

Either way, is there a better, more optimal approach still using **HTTP authentication** and **PHP Sessions** but that doesn't involve this sort of tricky javascript?

Comment: See above: _"I have an idea why it works but - and **this** is my question - I suspect there may be **a much more optimal solution** [...] is there a better, more optimal approach still using **HTTP authentication** and **PHP Sessions** but that doesn't involve this sort of tricky javascript?"_

Comment: Why do you want to involve HTTP Auth in the first place here? Is there actual static files behind those paths/inside the realms, that should be served directly by the web server, but be protected from unauthorized access?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Static files, protected from unauthorised access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unclear whether using a javascript redirect on a custom 401 page (for users who cancel the authentication console) is a legitimate approach or constitutes nothing more than a convenient hack, but I've come to terms with using it for now.

I'll call it the **Authentication Sandwich**.

---

Usefully, I've realised that, rather than the over-complex process of:

1. Re-locking the submenu on the custom `401 Unauthorised Page`
2. Flagging the visit to the custom `401 Unauthorised Page`
3. Redirecting via javascript back to the menu with a query string appended
4. Processing a conditional block on the menu page *if* there has just been a redirect from the custom `401 Unauthorised Page`.
5. And if there *has*, checking if there is a query string appended to the URL.
6. And if there *isn't*, then using javascript to click again on the submenu.

(It was *preposterously* complex, wasn't it?)

I can replace all the above with a much simpler alternative:

**A javascript redirect in the `<head>` of the custom `401 Unauthorised Page` which accesses an intermediate page which i) re-locks the submenu; and ii) returns to the menu**

That's it.

- No need to flag the visit to the custom `401 Unauthorised Page`
- No need for any query strings
- No need for a conditional block on the menu page
- No need for an over-elaborate use of javascript to click again on the selected submenu

Much, *much* simpler and more straightforward.